# Limitations in zedgraphweb

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I'm trying to create candle stick chart using zedgraphweb and having below problems.

1. How to add horizontal scroll bar to chart. There are methods for this for ZEDGRAPH but none in zedgraphweb.
2. How to refresh just graph to render real time data with out page refresh. Calling this.ZedGraphWeb1.RenderGraph += new ZedGraph.Web.ZedGraphWebControlEventHandler(this.OnRenderGraph); refreshing the entire graph.
3. How to add tool tips?

Thanks,
Thavva

Comment: You should ask three separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

2) I don't know the differences between zedGraph and zedGraphWeb, but in zedGraph, the `zedGraphControl.Refresh()` method enables you to refresh the graph pane.